# Update of Dependencies & Libraries

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I am working on a two-year-old project, which was last used in Q1/2020. Now I want to update all dependencies and libraries, but the following error message pops up when I do "npm i" or "npm install":

> [image]

"npm i --force" or "npm i --legacy-peer-deps" doesn't work either.

What can be done here? In general, I'd want to work with the most up-to-date platforms e.g. react, node, and the remaining packages in package.json.

Any recommendations? Friends recommend updating all dependencies one by one, but I have no idea how to do this. I've tried but then everything seems to fail.

Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: If you read the error, node is asking you to upgrade npm. You can do so by installing a newer version of Node.js. The latest version of npm is 8.3.1.

Comment: I tried to install the latest version of npm but it says that it doesn't work with Nodejs >=14. Unfortunately, my app doesn't work with anything higher than nodejs 13.

Comment: Downgrade npm then

Comment: Can you share the package.json?